# Change "View Basket" Button Text Colour To White On Hover (Wordpress with Woocommerce)

Tags: css, wordpress, woocommerce

I have tried every single CSS code under the sun to try change the rollover text "view basket" to white when the button is hovered (currently grey background and black text when hovered). Wordpress with Woocommerce setup.

https://www.charliecustards.co.uk/product/the-charlie-new-orleans-black-on-black-brogue-boot-in-calf-leather-suede/

To see real time simply add the shoe to the basket and you will see the view basket button which is having the problems on rollover. Also see screenshot.

I tried everything to get hold of the button in the css and simply change it, but nothing would work.This was the last code i tried and don't understand why it won't work?!

```css
.woocommerce-page .woocommerce-message a.button.wc-forward:hover {
  color: #ffffff !important;
}
```

Help on this would be so appreciated, its driving me mad.I've tried every div, selector etc associated with the button and nothing will work. The code above was one of many but i think the closest.

Thank you so much.

[image: screenshot]

Comment: #000000 is for black. Try with #ffffff.

Comment: Or try this: `.woocommerce #fl-main-content .fl-theme-builder-woo-notices .woocommerce-message a.button:hover { color: #fff !important; }` https://nimb.ws/eoqC0U

Comment: Thank you so much, this works. I spent hours trying to get the right selectors so this helped me learn. Appreciated, honestly!

How do i rate you 5 star or give you a thumbs up etc?

Comment: That comment is enough for me.